# How to connect office 365 site having MFA using c#

Tags: development, office-365, csom, authentication, console-application

I need to connect Office 365 site using console application(c#). but the problem is office 365 tenant having MFA(**Multi Factor Authentication**) authentication. How can i connect to specific site collection using C#?

Is anyone have worked on console application to connect office 365 having MFA enabled?

Comment: it gives 403 error straightaway unfortunately. Tried in c# and powershell both, same result.

Comment: Is there any alternative way to connect?

Comment: don't think so , for us, we had to remove/disable it for that specific user and then connect

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25969814/how-to-do-multi-factor-authentication-with-sharepoint-online-using-csom - read comments on this link, maybe it can give you some idea

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to connect to O365 site using c#, microsoft has just released workaround for the powershell

https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell/blob/master/Documentation/ConnectPnPOnline.md